# Excel cell value as SQL Server Connection parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-2013

I'm trying to get SQL Server 2012 data into Excel 2013.

You can see my sample command text. If I write date parameter manually, like this:

```
set @dt = getdate()
```

it works well. But I need to pass it the Excel cell value, for example `A1` value as shown in the picture. Is it possible? If yes, how?

**Please note**: I do **NOT** want to use vba macro connection, need to pass it via this form only.

[image]

Comment: If you used Microsoft Query rather than a data connection file, "Parameters..." would be available. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd

Comment: No, this works in Excel 2013 just as well. Use Data -> From Other Sources -> From Microsoft Query, define a query, and use parameter placeholders (`?`) in it. This will allow you to bind parameters to cells. Query is ancient and it has some restrictions, but it does work in 2013. Source: I just tested it.

Comment: Query has a "SQL" button that should allow you to input any single SQL statement you like, as long as SQL Server can run it. Query will complain it can't represent the query, but that's OK -- you're under no obligation to use the designer. (If you have multiple statements, it's no good.) That said, without knowing your exact query (which is probably more complicated than `SELECT * FROM [..]`, then) I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Another option that works in conjunction with Query for multi-statement queries is to leverage stored procedures; you can make those as complicated as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Jeroen's answer applies to SQL Queries also, but it's not obvious how to implement them, since Excel doesn't appear to expose the option in advance, and the 'parameter' button is grayed out.

Write the query with question marks in place of the value to be [used in the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMYFu.png):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE AS T where t.Date = ?
```

Upon saving the query, [a prompt appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwyk2.png) that lets you select a cell or range to use as the value in place of the question mark.